# Matching items in two arrays

Tags: php, arrays, string-matching

Right i've got two arrays that i'm trying to compare to see if words match between them.

```
$address = explode(",", '31 Birmingham Road, Erdington, Birmingham, Blah');
```

I'm using the following which doesn't find any matches however when exploring the loop I can get Erdington = Erdington and it still returns no match?

```
if (count($_POST['location'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['location'] as $value) {
        if (in_array($value, $address)) {
            $exists = 1;
            $success[] = "Match";
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

The space after the comma is causing the test to fail. If the addresses will always have that space you can use @SharpEdge's answer. If it's optional, use `trim()`

```
$address = array_map('trim', explode(",", '31 Birmingham Road, Erdington, Birmingham, Blah'));
```

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that the space after the comma is causing the condition to fail.

`' Erdington' != 'Erdington'`

Dirty test (adding a space in the delimiter after the comma)

```
$address = explode(", ", '31 Birmingham Road, Erdington, Birmingham, Blah');
```